# class svg :hover css fill not working correctly

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I cause this svg to fill when I hover?  I looked at a fair amount of documentation and tried several ways but was unsuccessfully.

Here is my html:

```
  <a class="anchor-class" href="#"><svg class="svg-class"></svg></a>
```

And i have tried the following in my css

```
a svg:hover {
    fill: #50c8e8;
}
```

as well as

```
.anchor-class svg:hover{
    fill: #50c8e8;
}
```

and even

```
.svg-class :hover{
    fill:#50c8e8;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I should be able to accomplish this with css, right?

EDIT:  It might help to note that this image is being used as a background image.  a little more detail in the css below:

```
.svg-class {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    .background-image('path.svg')
}
```

EDIT 2:  Here is the .svg code, not sure that it is important though

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#E4E4E4;}
</style>
<path id="XMLID_154_" class="st0" d="M85.5,15c-19.5-19.4-51-19.4-70.4,0c-19.5,19.4-19.5,51,0,70.4c19.5,19.5,51,19.4,70.4,0
C105,66,105,34.4,85.5,15z M49.5,9c5.3,0,9.5,4.3,9.5,9.5c0,5.3-4.3,9.6-9.5,9.6c-5.3,0-9.6-4.3-9.6-9.6C39.9,13.2,44.1,9,49.5,9z
 M64.8,79.1c0,2-1,3-3,3H37.3c-2,0-3-1-3-3v-6.3c0-2,1-3,3-3h4.5V43.4h-4.6c-2,0-3-1-3-3v-6.3c0-2,1-3,3-3h17.2c2,0,3,1,3,3v35.7
h4.6c2,0,3,1,3,3V79.1z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D I see this now.  I didn't realize that using the svg as a `.background-image` would change it.  Thanks.  Feel free to delete

Comment: You can delete the question if you wish. I can't do that.

Comment: Nor can John Carpenter deletes his answer first

Comment: OK...just have to stay then although I don't know if you can flag it for a moderator (which I'm not) to delete?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UPDATE: with the svg code that you posted, you can do this behavior in this way.

Example:

```css
a .svg-class:hover path {
    fill: #50c8e8;
}

.svg-class {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="anchor-class" href="#">
  <svg class="svg-class" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#E4E4E4;}
    </style>
    <path id="XMLID_154_" class="st0" d="M85.5,15c-19.5-19.4-51-19.4-70.4,0c-19.5,19.4-19.5,51,0,70.4c19.5,19.5,51,19.4,70.4,0
C105,66,105,34.4,85.5,15z M49.5,9c5.3,0,9.5,4.3,9.5,9.5c0,5.3-4.3,9.6-9.5,9.6c-5.3,0-9.6-4.3-9.6-9.6C39.9,13.2,44.1,9,49.5,9z
 M64.8,79.1c0,2-1,3-3,3H37.3c-2,0-3-1-3-3v-6.3c0-2,1-3,3-3h4.5V43.4h-4.6c-2,0-3-1-3-3v-6.3c0-2,1-3,3-3h17.2c2,0,3,1,3,3v35.7
h4.6c2,0,3,1,3,3V79.1z"/>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: But this way you can't apply a transition speed...